# Stuck mid-way through Root process (Samsung Galaxy S3 SCH-1535)

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-3, recovery-mode, twrp

[Root Instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2046439)

I've been following the root instructions above. I'm at this step:

Using your custom recovery flash the download you chose above from Step 1 (#3)

However, I had forgotten to move the SU/Bootloader zip file to my SDCard (not a removable SD, the system SD). So I connected to my mac, used android file transfer to move the zip file to the SD card root directory (/sdcard/), and rebooted into recovery mode.

Now I'm in the samsung recovery mode (3e), with the little android fella and the red triangle, (manual mode), and if I select 'external storage', obviously since I don't have any (no removable SD), I can't seem to get to the file.

The first time I had rebooted into recovery I had gotten this screen:

[TWRP Screen](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&sa=N&biw=1313&bih=681&tbm=isch&tbnid=EucLO-vjh0h0dM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.xda-developers.com/android/twrp-2-1-released-for-the-att-and-rogers-one-x/&docid=uQNdNHM5ox81EM&imgurl=http://www.xda-developers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Hoge.png&w=480&h=800&ei=vO1KUf2eMabk4APA-IH4Dg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:0,s:0,i:84&iact=rc&dur=1432&page=1&tbnh=168&tbnw=101&start=0&ndsp=20&tx=37&ty=46)

But now I can't seem to get back to that screen to attempt to install the Super SU and Bootloader zip file.

Help?

Comment: How is it not working? You can't access any recovery, or you can only access stock recovery?

Comment: I'm supposed to be at the step where I "flash" the SU and bootloader, but am unable to do so. I'm not sure if it's 'not working' or 'working', what I'm saying is that, while following the instructions linked above, I'm unable to complete them and don't know why.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or error message? "it's not working" isn't enough info.

Comment: OK--so, again, Not once do I utter 'It's not working'...But regardless, here is someone else's screenshot that is identical to mine. http://rootgalaxys3iii.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Galaxy-S3-Android-System-recovery-Mode_thumb.jpg

Comment: So it's showing the system recovery. That's what I was asking earlier. You need to re-flash TWRP and then install the zip.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I got that done, did what you suggested, that threw its own error which was that the .zip file I had pulled from the tutorial was not valid for whatever reason (and googling, some other folks seem to have the same issue), but TWRP itself went ahead and finished the root and installed SuperSU, etc. So, thanks!

Comment: Now I'm just trying to figure out which ROM I want to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put this here so you can mark your question as answered.

Some phones' stock ROMs automatically replace custom recoveries with the stock ones on boot, so when you rebooted to put the ZIP on your phone, TWRP was wiped away. So, simple, reinstall it.

As for a good ROMs, I use [ParanoidAndroid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1858298) on my Galaxy Nexus and I love it.